# If session or cookie is set, append query string to URLs across the whole domain

Tags: php, session, url, cookies, query-string

We have a PHP app that uses dynamic branding, so if we insert the query string

`?dealer=the_dealer_name` or `&dealer=the_dealer_name`, we are able to dynamically load that dealer's logo and stylesheet on our main platform without having to log in to the dealer's account (we sell the app to thousands of dealers). This works fine but the app has several pages and if we are demonstrating the app we don't want to add the query string every time we open a new page.

So the idea is to set either a cookie or a session when the `$_GET['dealer']` is set and not empty and make the query string persistent across the whole app so we don't need to keep adding it for every page during the demos. We will put an expiration time of one hour to that cookie/session. We will also add the ability to unset them if we pass an empty string to the 'dealer' query such as `?dealer=`.

I wanted to know if there is any way I can add the `?dealer=the_dealer_name` / `&dealer=the_dealer_name` query string to the url after it is set for the first time and make it persist as the last query string of the URL until the cookie/session expires.

To summarize, once we pass the query string `?dealer=the_dealer_name` or `&dealer=the_dealer_name` to the URL, all URL paths on the site will have that query string appended, unless we pass an empty string as the parameter and unset the cookie/session, or the cookie/session expires.

Thank you!

P.S. getting the URL via `$_SERVER` globals, adding the query string, and redirecting using `header()` may not work because I have to put the logic in my header file. Any loaded page needs to redirect to itself but with an appended query string, which will create redirects on top of redirects.

Comment: If you set a cookie, why not read it from the cookie instead of from the URL?

Comment: Yes, basically what @JasonMcCreary suggested. If you store it in a cookie or session, just ignore the URL, and use the value from there. Something like this (for sessions) `if(isset($_SESSION['dealer_name']) { $dealer = $_SESSION['dealer_name']; } else { $dealer = $_GET['dealer']; }`

Comment: @AlexSzabó that is what I was doing but how do I use the `$dealer` to make the dealer's information persistent? Getting it on all pages will be a lot of work. I was wondering it there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it easily to a session, put this on top of your page:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['dealer'])) $_SESSION['dealer'] = $_GET['dealer'];
//then get the $_SESSION['dealer'] on all pages
```

This starts the session, and stores the dealer variable if its in the quesrystring, and it will be availible to all subsequent page loads. Depending on what you do with the string, you might want to escape it or use whitelisting.

If you want to remove the session (and take away the branding) you can run `session_destroy();`

Comment: And how do I use `$_SESSION['dealer'] ` to load the dealer's info on every page, zedd?

Comment: use it as you would the $_GET['dealer'] (as long as you session_start(), you have access to the variable set on the previous page loads)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielFerraz glad it worked, now take note that you need to escape/parametrize it properly if you are getting it from a database to protect from malicious use

Comment: we just test if the name is on our brands.csv and from there we have a logic in place that takes care of pulling the dealer's info from the db. The dealer name taken from the query string is never used to do db inserts, selects, or updates. I am escaping it just as good practice though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is setting `.htaccess` assuming you are using `apache`

Append particluar query string when page is requested

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ ?dealer=the_dealer_name [L,QSA,NC]
```

when not in use, just comment it

```
# RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ ?dealer=the_dealer_name [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: How can I make 'the_dealer_name ' dynamic', Viral? We need to be able to change it on the fly.

Comment: no, not that i know, you need to update `.htaccess` everytime,